# Find best matching string using Levenshtein distance algorithm

Tags: java, regex, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to implement the Levenshtein distance algorithm to find the most similar match

The list is like

```
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add("*");
    values.add("3.63.161.2");
    values.add("3*");
    values.add("*2");
    values.add("3*1");
    values.add("3.1*");
    values.add("3.2*");
    values.add("3.3*");
    values.add("3.4*");
    values.add("3.5*");
    values.add("3.61*");
    values.add("3*0");
    values.add("2*");
    values.add("1*");
    values.add("3.62*");

 String stringToMatch = "3.63.162.2";

 for (String pattern : values) {
        String regex = pattern.replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".*");
        System.out.println("String ["+stringToMatch+"] matches with ["+pattern+"] :  "+ stringToMatch.matches(regex) +" and the difference is --> "+StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(stringToMatch, pattern));

    }
```

The output of this is what I am expecting

```
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [*] :  true and the difference is --> 10
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.63.161.2] :  false and the difference is --> 1
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3*] :  true and the difference is --> 9
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [*2] :  true and the difference is --> 9
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3*1] :  false and the difference is --> 8
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.1*] :  false and the difference is --> 7
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.2*] :  false and the difference is --> 7
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.3*] :  false and the difference is --> 7
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.4*] :  false and the difference is --> 8
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.5*] :  false and the difference is --> 8
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.61*] :  false and the difference is --> 6
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3*0] :  false and the difference is --> 9
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [2*] :  false and the difference is --> 9
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [1*] :  false and the difference is --> 9
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3.62*] :  false and the difference is --> 6
```

So the nearest matching strings are

```
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [3*] :  true and the difference is --> 9
String [3.63.162.2] matches with [*2] :  true and the difference is --> 9
```

What I would like to have is give 3* as the most matching because the first character is matching.

So is there a way to match the strings from left to right using the same technique.

I know I can separately write a code to match but I would like  to look at other approaches as well.

Comment: You misspelled *matches*

Comment: you know you can get this algorithm from apache commons, right?

Comment: @leo Yes I am using the same StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance, but my question is if the distance is same , I want to chose the one which match the most starting from left.

Comment: @blueygh2, that was a typo in the sysout , I corrected that :)